# Finding λ that maximize log-likelihood using R

Tags: r

Question: Find λ that maximize log-likelihood

Codes provided:

> loglikelihood<−function(lambda){sum(dpois(counts ,lambda, log=T))}
>
> lambdas <− seq(1,15, len=300)
>
> result<−sapply(lambdas , loglikelihood )

So far I found out that the lambda position using the code

> which(result==max(result))

[1] 62

I do not know what code to use to pick out the lambda on the 62th position using lambdas (values)

Comment: Please type your question as text, do not just post a photograph (see 
[here](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3176/)). When you retype the question,
add the `[self-study]` tag & read 
[its wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). 
Then tell us what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. 
We'll provide hints to help you get unstuck. Please make these changes as just 
posting your homework & hoping someone will do it for you is grounds for closing.

Comment: Check out `result[62]` and `which.max()`.  You probably also want to find the maximum using something like `optim()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
# index (lambda)
which(result == max(result)) / (15-1)
# log likelihood
result[which(result == max(result))]
```

I would assume this would work.  However I am not testing because there is no reproducible example.